# Authentication with Swift using Joss

Tags: java, authentication, token, openstack-swift

I created an `Account (joss.model.Account)` , in the configuration

```
allowReauthenticate=true
```

Almost immidiateley after account creation I call

```
Access mAccess = mAccount.authenticate(); // (joss.model.Access)
```

After that I need to use the token. I use it after 30 min and 1.5h and 24h etc.
by calling `mAccess.getToken()` Token expatriation time is 1h.
Can I suppose that re-authentication will be performed and after 1.5h as well after 24 h the token will be valid? Or I need to re-authenticate manually?

I.e. `mAccess.getToken()` will return invalid (expired token) after 1.5h and 24h.
How to re-authenticate correctly in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `mAccount.authenticate()` once `mAccess.getToken()` returns invalid. Forget about time in the client app, it must be re-entrant.

Handle UI around that (re-enter username/password if needed before authenticate() method if existing credentials prove to be useless).

Comment: Do you know how can I know token expiry time?

Comment: If your API nor documentation does not provide this value, you have to use trial/error. 

When you get the token, save a timestamp + 3600 seconds with it. If you compare that to current time, you can expect the token to be expired after 1 hour.

Or just use the token you have and in case it fails, it means it's expired.